# wordpress url rewriting error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /ams/amsproduct.php?lotno=$1 [L]
```

I am addding a php page to my wordpress website and i want the url rewritten in .htaccess file.

```
from http://example.com/ams/amsproduct.php?lotno=223
to http://example.com/223
```

but wordpress pages are broken when i add the  htaccess above.

But all works works when i add a .html file to the code like.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html?$ /ams/amsproduct.php?lotno=$1 [L]
```

But the result looks like this `http://example.com/223.html` and i dont want that.

I want a result like this `http://example.com/223`.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to create a separate PHP page. Is there any specific reason? You should use WordPress built-in page/template functionality.

I would like to suggest you to check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) which includes all the information you need to make your own custom page/template in WordPress.